# Manipulating an options array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm developing an OpenSource project in PHP and I need to manipulate options arrays.

I'm looking to do these things with functions, here under are the examples of what I'm trying to do.
I don't know if it's the right way to manage this, maybe there's some other options, or maybe an already made class that can handle all of this, I'm all open to solutions.

```
// Define an array of options
$arr = array(
  'options' => array(
    'levelA' => array(
      'property1' => 'value1',
      'property2' => 'value2',
    ),
    'levelB' => array(
      'property3' => 'value3',
      'property4' => 'value4',
    ),
    'levelC' => array(
      'property5' => 'value5',
      'property6' => 'value6',
    )
  )
)

// Remove the property5 in levelC in options.
$arr = array_delete_value($arr, array('options', 'levelC', 'property5'));

// Result array
$arr = array(
  'options' => array(
    'levelA' => array(
      'property1' => 'value1',
      'property2' => 'value2',
    ),
    'levelB' => array(
      'property3' => 'value3',
      'property4' => 'value4',
    ),
    'levelC' => array(
      'property6' => 'value6',
    )
  )
)

// Delete the levelB in options.
$arr = array_delete_value($arr, array('options', 'levelB'));

// Result array
$arr = array(
  'options' => array(
    'levelA' => array(
      'property1' => 'value1',
      'property2' => 'value2',
    ),
    'levelC' => array(
      'property6' => 'value6',
    )
  )
)

// Set a new value in the options in options -> levelD -> property7. Create it if needed.
$arr = array_set_value(array('options', 'levelD', 'property7'), 'value7');

// Result array
$arr = array(
  'options' => array(
    'levelA' => array(
      'property1' => 'value1',
      'property2' => 'value2',
    ),
    'levelC' => array(
      'property6' => 'value6',
    ),
    'levelD' => array(
      'property7' => 'value7',
    )
  )
)

// Create an array of options in options -> levelD
$arr = array_set_value(array('options', 'levelD'), array('property8' => 'value8', 'property9' => 'value9'));

// Result array
$arr = array(
  'options' => array(
    'levelA' => array(
      'property1' => 'value1',
      'property2' => 'value2',
    ),
    'levelC' => array(
      'property6' => 'value6',
    ),
    'levelD' => array(
      'property8' => 'value8',
      'property9' => 'value9',
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: This looks like Object material -- the data structure and transactions are complicated enough and to be a class in their own right.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove values from an array doing [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) i.e.

```
unset($arr['options']['levelC']['property5']);
```

You can also simply add things to php arrays by doing

```
$arr['options']['levelD'] = array('property8' => 'value8', 'property9' => 'value9');
```

I suggest looking more into what [Arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) can do.

Don't reinvent the wheel if you do not have to. I am uncertain why you would need a class to create these. Perhaps you can clarify in a comment for me? Regardless, if you had to write a class of your own to perform more complicated tasks, you can at least leverage the functions I specified above.

Answer (score 0):

I created some functions that does exactly what I needed. My code is inspired from this: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_array_get_nested_value/7 and this: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_array_set_nested_value/7